# Login failed for user 'sa' State: 8, in short time

Tags: sql-server, authentication, logging

I have setup SQL Server on server Customer.

Recently, log files in SQL Server increase continuously. I checked the content of those logs - see here:

[image]

In my application I use an account for connecting to the SQL Server database. I tried to disable the `sa` account in SQL Server. However, errors are still being logged.

Maybe my database is being attacked?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is very likely that your SQL Server is under attack. I suggest you talk to your network people immediately and make sure that your SQL Server isn't exposed to the Internet. You have the source IP addresses if you want to dig further, but I doubt that will lead you anywhere useful.